# Results display issue with Content search webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online

The paging in the content search webpart is not working properly.
When we click on the next page tab/icon on the webpart, the next page just blinks and automatically returns to the initial page. Please suggest if i am missing any settings to be done for the webpart. I am using SharePoint online/Office 365.

Thank You